# IIS Failed request tracing - Trace Providers

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm working on an IIS 7.5 server and enabled the failed request tracing feature however when I attempt to setup the rules I only have an option to select ASPNET as a provider rather than the normal four providers (ASP, ASPNET, ISAPI Extension, WWW Server).

Does anyone know how to get the other providers to display?

[FRT - Provider - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCYQ3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it seems your traceProviderDefinitions got cleared or something. to fix that you can:

1. Make a backup of c:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Config\ApplicationHost.config just in case anything goes wrong with your XML editing.
2. Open c:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Config\ApplicationHost.config in notepad.
3. Look for: , in my machine I have the following:

   ```
           <traceProviderDefinitions>
           <add name="WWW Server" guid="{3a2a4e84-4c21-4981-ae10-3fda0d9b0f83}">
               <areas>
                   <clear />
                   <add name="Authentication" value="2" />
                   <add name="Security" value="4" />
                   <add name="Filter" value="8" />
                   <add name="StaticFile" value="16" />
                   <add name="CGI" value="32" />
                   <add name="Compression" value="64" />
                   <add name="Cache" value="128" />
                   <add name="RequestNotifications" value="256" />
                   <add name="Module" value="512" />
                   <add name="Rewrite" value="1024" />
                   <add name="FastCGI" value="4096" />
                   <add name="WebSocket" value="16384" />
               </areas>
           </add>
           <add name="ASP" guid="{06b94d9a-b15e-456e-a4ef-37c984a2cb4b}">
               <areas>
                   <clear />
               </areas>
           </add>
           <add name="ISAPI Extension" guid="{a1c2040e-8840-4c31-ba11-9871031a19ea}">
               <areas>
                   <clear />
               </areas>
           </add>
           <add name="ASPNET" guid="{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35}">
               <areas>
                   <add name="Infrastructure" value="1" />
                   <add name="Module" value="2" />
                   <add name="Page" value="4" />
                   <add name="AppServices" value="8" />
               </areas>
           </add>
       </traceProviderDefinitions>
   ```